# case expression with count and condition of count is greater then

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have the below table

Table A

```
PK    status_cd  id    grp  grp_rnk_asc  grp_rnk_desc   action_dt
154    new       10    1     1             4               11/6/2019
154    pending   10    1     2             3               11/7/2019
154    pending   10    1     3             2               11/8/2019
154    approved  10    1     4             1               11/9/2019
```

I want to...

`Count` `partition` with `condition` and when that `count` is `>` then 1 then 'pass'

Then be able to add additional `when` to the `case expression`

For example:

Sample of criteria

```
select 
Count when status_cd not in ('new','approved') 
over (partition by id,grp order by action_dt) if that count > 1 then 'pass'

--also be able to add new conditions here...
from A
--no where clause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select (case when sum(case when tatus_cd not in ('new',' approved') then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id, grp) > 1
             then 'pass'
        end)
from A
```